# Encrypted data not being inserted into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, mcrypt

I'm trying to upgrade my encryption routines from des to blowfish. I have this function for en/decryption:

```
function NewCryptStr($EncryptOrDecrypt,$Str)
{
  $Key='test';

  $IVSize=mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
  $IV=mcrypt_create_iv($IVSize,MCRYPT_RAND);

  if($EncryptOrDecrypt==='Encrypt')
    {
      $Str=mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,$Key,$Str,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,$IV);
      $Str=mysql_real_escape_string($Str);
    }

  if($EncryptOrDecrypt==='Decrypt')
    $Str=mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,$Key,$Str,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,$IV);

  return $Str;
}
```

This works fine:

```
$Str='test string to be encrypted then decrypted';
print "<p>Original $Str</p>\n";
$Str=NewCryptStr('Encrypt',$Str);
print "<p>Encrypted $Str</p>\n";
$Str=NewCryptStr('Decrypt',$Str);
print "<p>Decrypted $Str</p>\n";
```

Then I'm running the following php script on a table of email addresses to convert a column of plain text & update another column with the encrypted result:

```
$sql="select UID,Str from testdata order by UID";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$Link);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $Encrypted=NewCryptStr('Encrypt',$row[Str]);

    $sql="update testdata set Str2='$Encrypted' where UID=$row[UID]";
    print "<p>$row[Str] > $Encrypted</p>\n";
    print "<p>$sql</p>\n";
    mysql_query($sql,$Link) or die("failed $sql ".mysql_error());
  }
```

It runs without error & prints out a load of encrypted strings as I'd expect but when I view the data in the table none of the records have been updated with the same data that was printed by the php above. Instead most of the values in Str2 are blank some have 1 or 2 characters in them.

All the sql statements printed look fine, & running them individually updates the record correctly.

The sql tables & the mysql connection are both using utf8 encoding, Str & Str2 columns are varchar datatypes.

Why isn't my table being updated with the correct data?

**Edit** I have solved (skirted round!) the issue using base encoding/decoding the output/input of NewCryptStr function. I'm still curious to know why my loop through the table wasn't working when the sql statements happily worked when executed individually.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, I'd strongly suggest you switch to PDO or mysqli. Also, why is your `$EncryptOrDecrypt` variable a case sensitive string, instead of a boolean?

And where exactly is it that you view the data that doesn't show as expected? PHP will grab the data that is currently in the tables, if PHP finds the correct data, then the correct data is there.

Comment: The mysql upgrade is on the todo list, the $EncryptOrDecrypt variable is just for my readability while I'm trying to build something that works. I'm viewing the data in phpmyadmin. PHP is not finding the correct data, as I said the encrypted data printed by the line `print "<p>$row[Str] > $Encrypted</p>\n";` is not what is ending up in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You have in your code: `$row[UID]`, which is not defined, so no records will be updated.

Change `$row[UID]` to `$row['UID']`;

Use:

```
$sql="UPDATE testdata SET Str2='".$Encrypted."' WHERE UID=".$row['UID'];
```

Comment: Actually PHP handles that quite nicely, although I'll agree `$row['UID']` is the best, along with keeping variables outside the quotes.

Comment: Trying all combinations of $row[UID] & $row['UID'] both inside & outside the quotes produces the same result.

Comment: Very strange. Please paste here one of the printed $sql-s.

Comment: Example: `update testdata set Str='�r����B���n�' where UID=1` I have since worked around the issue (see edit) but still would like to know what exactly was wrong!

Comment: What I pointed out was for sure a problem. Other problems I don't see in your linked code. You also should `base64_encode` before inserting in database (to not have a lot of strange characters). Also use `base64_decode` before decode.

Comment: @Thorbear Actually PHP reports notices when you use `$row[UID]` and `UID` is not defined. It then assumes that you meant `$row['UID']`. The code will not work in the same way when the constant `UID` is defined. Imho notices are just as bad as errors and warnings.

Comment: @Arjan it doesn't produce a notice when it is put inside quotes though, and if the queries print with the correct UIDs in place, then this was not the problem, but again, I agree that `$row['UID']` is the correct way to write it.

Comment: @Tamas Pap Yes, the base64 coding is exactly what I've done to solve the problem. The issue of variables in the sql statements will disappear when I change the site to use prepared statements, I know the code is deprecated & I promise it will be replaced :) but I don't think it is relevant to the original question.